# Determine if `set -e` flag if is active in bash

Tags: bash

In a bash script/shell, is there a programmatic way to determine if the `set -e` flag is active?

I just need a boolean letting me know if it's on/off.

Comment: I am not sure which answer is best or which to accept tbh

Comment: I'd just pick whichever one you actually used, but be sure to upvote all the ones that were helpful.

Answer (score 7):

From `help test`:

```
    -o OPTION      True if the shell option OPTION is enabled.
```

Thus:

```sh
[ -o errexit ]
```

Comment: ohhh so `set -e` is short for `set -o errexit`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the exit code of `shopt`:

```
if shopt -qo errexit; then 
    echo enabled
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: shopt -qo errexit && echo enabled || echo disabled

Comment: @ctec +1 for the `-q`, I missed that ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `$-` variable to see whether the **e** option is enabled:

```sh
[[ $- =~ e ]]
```

From `help set`:

```
The current set of flags may be found in $-.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ set -e
$ if grep -q 'errexit' <<<"$SHELLOPTS";then echo "set -e is enabled";else echo "set -e is disabled";fi
set -e is enabled
$ set +e
$ if grep -q 'errexit' <<<"$SHELLOPTS";then echo "set -e is enabled";else echo "set -e is disabled";fi
set -e is disabled
```