# How to view current shell/sh/bash status to know if it is set -e or set +e?

Tags: shell, exit

We use `set -e` to halt a shell script if error occurs, and use `set +e` to turn it off.

My question is how to know the current status of this -e/+e ?

My [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+view+current+shell+status+to+know+if+it+is+set+-e+or+set+%2Be&oq=how+to+view+current+shell+status+to+know+if+it+is+set+-e+or+set+%2Be&aqs=chrome..69i57.21534j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How%20to%20view%20current%20shell%2Fsh%2Fbash%20status%20to%20know%20if%20it%20is%20set%20-e%20or%20set%20%2Be%3F&searchOn=3) results very little helpful so I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same pattern works as for testing any other `set` flag:

```
case $- in
  *e*) echo "set -e is enabled";;
  *)   echo "set -e is not enabled";;
esac
```

View [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949201/determine-if-set-e-flag-if-is-active-in-bash)

Comment: Great thanks! It would be nice as you can share the source reference.

Comment: There are answers to [determine if `set -e` flag is active in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949201/determine-if-set-e-flag-if-is-active-in-bash) with references already present, so I just changed this answer to be community-wiki and flagged the question as a duplicate of the preexisting one.